# Using a webcam to put a face on a character

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm trying to accomplish something with flash but I'm having some problems, if not a solution I'm hoping someone can tell me a method and what I should read up on to do this:
I want to have an image on the stage that has a gap the shape of a face in the middle of it, I'd then like to put a webcam feed behind it so people can line their face up in the gap and press a button to take a picture. (I've managed to put the webcam on the stage and take the picture but can't work out how to put it behind an image). Then I cant quite work out how I'd put the face onto a character I've drawn.

Hope someone can help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of elements in your question, see if I can touch on them.

Place image on your avatar or wherever, you can add your image via the `addChild` method.  So, you can add the saved image like:

```
// Save image stuff
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
var video:Video = new Video(320,240);
video.attachCamera(cam);
video.x = 20;
video.y = 20;
addChild(video);

// Convert to bitmap image
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(video.width,video.height);
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
bitmap.x = 360;
bitmap.y = 20;

addChild(bitmap); // Add to your desire movie here
// Example yourContainer.addChild(bitmap);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's very similar to what i've got at the moment, except I only want to show the portion of the image that is the face. On the first one so they can line themselves up and I know where the face is and on the second bit so I know where to put the image of the face behind the character. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You can either rely on them to align their face up or allow them to crop the image (which is definitely more coding for you) - if you want to get into facial recognition, shape verification, etc... that's not a precise thing within flash right.  It's getting there.

Comment: I think I've missed a basic technique and I think it has something to do with not doing too much graphically in flash, I tend to stick just to the code but if I were to put an image in flash that had a circle in the middle, could I make it so the webcam image was behind the picture so you could only see a section of the feed inside the circle, the edges would be hidden behind the image?
Thanks for taking the time to answer, I'm not sure I'm explaining myself very well.

Comment: Oh, so you're wanting to mask the image, with say a circle?

Comment: Yes, would that be the best way if I just wanted the face? Get the user to move in front of the camera and press a button when their face shows up in the circle?

Comment: You could do that pretty easily, just do something like:  `camImageHere.cacheAsBitmap = true; 
circleMCname.cacheAsBitmap = true; 
camImageHere.mask = circleMCname; `